# In the FLRW metric, how do I convert from $k$ real to $k= -1,0,1$?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, space-expansion

In my notes I wrote that the FLRW metric is reported as
$$ ds^2 = -dt^2 + a(t)^2(  d\, \chi^2 +f_k(\chi)^2 d\,\Omega^2  )$$

with

$d\,\Omega^2=  d\theta^2 + \sin{\theta}^2 d\phi^2$ and

$$f_k(\chi)=
    \begin{cases}
      k^{-\frac{1}{2}} \sin{ \sqrt{k}\chi},& k>0,\quad \text{open universe}\\
      \chi & k=0,\quad \text{flat universe}\\
        (-k) ^ {-\frac{1}{2}} \sinh{\sqrt{-k}\chi},& k<0,\quad \text{closed universe} 
    \end{cases}  $$

but in the book it is instead reported as

$$ f_k(\chi)=
    \begin{cases}
       \sin{\chi},& k=1,\quad \text{open universe}\\
      \chi & k=0,\quad \text{flat universe}\\
          \sinh{\chi},& k=-1,\quad \text{closed universe} 
    \end{cases}  $$
what's the transformation that convert the first notation to the second one? Or did I make an error?

I cannot simply use $ \chi' = \sqrt{k} \chi$ since there is the factor $k$ outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full metric is
$$
ds^2 = - dt^2 + a(t)^2 [ d\chi^2 + \frac{1}{k} \sin^2 \sqrt{k} \chi  d \Omega^2 ] 
$$
For $k \neq 0$, we rescale $\chi \to \frac{1}{\sqrt{|k|}}\chi$ and redefine $a(t) \to \sqrt{|k|} a(t)$. Then, the metric is
$$
ds^2 = - dt^2 + a(t)^2 [ d\chi^2 + \sin^2 \chi d \Omega^2 ] . 
$$
which is the original metric but with $|k|=1$.

Comment: @Alucard - which square root?

Comment: nothing,   i was wrong